# How to call a state changing helper method in React?

Tags: reactjs

```
    state = { value:'' };
    count = (element) => () {
         this.setState({value:element});
    }

    render() {
       const elements = ['one','two','three'];
       return (
        <div>
          {
            elements.map( (element) => {
                 return <div onLoad = {this.count(element)}>{this.state.value}</div>
            }
          }
        <div>
        )
     }
```

onLoad function doesn't call.
By using onClick method in button it works.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `onLoad` is not a valid event in `div` elements.

Comment: @Raj, welcome on SO, please try to clean your code (I see multiple syntax errors) and specify why you want to do this so we can better help you. :)

Comment: @ChrisR i didn't see syntax errors dude.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix it like following for it to work:

```
state = { value:'' };
count = (element) => () {
     this.setState({value:element});
}

render() {
   const elements = ['one','two','three'];
   return (
    <div>
      {
        elements.map( (element) => {
             return <div onLoad={() => this.count(element)}>{this.state.value}</div>
        }
      }
    <div>
    )
 }
```

If you omit `() =>` it will call your function on component rendering, which is way before the click happens

Comment: I tried it dude. it doesn't work. @Evgenii Klepilin

Answer (score 0):

React is a script which running after page loads. So the load time has passed.

Div rendered in react component is created by react system on already loaded page. There is no such div during page loading time and some short time later after page loading completed.

Comment: @Crysfels already answered you in comment, I’m just clarifying why this function does not make sense in the react

Comment: i am just new to react. but i found onLoad function doesn't works. If i put some other event listener like onClick it works perfectly. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Keep it steady! Don't forget to vote here for helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear for me, what is the state you would like to reach, but I am willing to help.

Div elements do not "load". 
You can add event listener, but there should be a reason for that, for now, I can not see it.

Second point, you'd better never call setState from render. Because you will face the "Maximum update depth exceeded" error. So from you current state I would propose one redundant render. 
In general you need to re-think the design. SO could help with this, if you provide more details as it is requested in comments to you post.

```
import React from 'react';

const elements = ['one','two','three'];

class App extends  React.Component {
  state = {
    value: null
  };

  count = element => {
    this.setState({ value: element });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    elements.map(el => this.count(el))
  };

  render() {
    return elements.map(el => <div key={el}>{el}</div>)
  };
}


export default App;
```

Comment: i am just new to react. but i found onLoad function doesn't works. If i put some other event listener like onClick it works perfectly. thanks for your reply.@Mark Kovalenko